# Equivalent to Rails' polymorphic associations in Entity Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-framework

I'm working to port part of an existing Ruby on Rails application to .NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 (don't ask), and need some help replicating some ORM functionality, particularly Rails' polymorphic associations.

I would rather not change the existing database structions.  I'll give one example of what I'm doing -- here's what the database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE taggings (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_id integer REFERENCES tags(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    taggable_id integer,
    taggable_type nvarchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE stories (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
    [more stuff]
);

CREATE TABLE assets (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
    [more stuff]
);
```

The Taggings model is associated with several others, such as Story, Asset, etc.  Records in this table looks like:

```
INSERT INTO taggings values (1, 1, 1234, 'Story');
INSERT INTO taggings values (2, 343, 69, 'Asset');
INSERT INTO taggings values (3, 200, 42, 'Asset');
```

Thus, both the Asset and Story models in the domain have a one-to-many relationship with Taggings.  I'd like to model (Fluent API) this relationship on my C# Story and Asset classes.

Is there a way to specify this, perhaps with an additional condition (Tagging.taggable_type = 'Story') when defining the relationship?  I don't need to navigate the other direction (from Tagging to Story/Asset).

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 2):

Make EF acts like ActiveRecord it's not going to work, but you can do something similar.
You have a class Taggable that acts like the polymorphic class and that class has and belongs to many Tags, your other classes inherit from Taggable that makes them "Taggable" so for example Article : Taggable so inside the object you will have something like

article.Tags -> because article is Taggable and a Taggable has many Tags.

Below is the code tested and working

`

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Taggable> Taggables { get; set; }
}

public class Taggable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

[Table("Quests")]
public class Quest : Taggable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string QuestType { get; set; }
}

[Table("Articles")]
public class Article : Taggable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ArticleType { get; set; }
}

public class Repository : DbContext
{
    public Repository() : base("Blog")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Taggable> Taggables { get; set; }
}
```

`

so you can do stuff like this

`

```
        Repository r = new Repository();
        Article a = new Article();
        a.Tags = r.Tags.ToList();
        a.Name = "article 1";
        r.Taggables.Add(a);

        Quest q = new Quest();
        q.Tags = r.Tags.ToList().Skip(2).ToList();
        r.Taggables.Add(q);

        r.SaveChanges();

        var bb = from ttt in r.Taggables
                 where ttt is Article
                 select ttt;

        var jj = bb.ToList();
```

`

I hope I solved your question.